# How to create dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have list like below
(in this example,it represent as list,but this is need not to be given as list)

```
age=[3,4,5,6]

sex=[1,2]

limit=[3,4]
```

I would like to create dataframe which has every combination.

but the 'limit' column is more than 'age' columns.

So my desired result is like this.

```
age sex limit
3   1    3
3   1    4
4   1    4
3   2    3  
3   2    4
4   2    4
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: ok, what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can get this result with a bit of programming. Have you tried?

Comment: Hint: use for ... for .. if .. etc. Show us your attempt here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses Numpy and Pandas to create a data frame of combinations using the constraint that 'limit' is greater than or equal to 'age'.  Note that your post says 'greater than' but your example of output shows 'greater than or equal to'.:

```
import itertools
age=[3,4,5,6]
sex=[1,2]
limit=[3,4]
a = [age, sex, limit]
mylist = list(itertools.product(*a))

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(mylist).reshape(len(mylist),3), columns = ["age","sex","limit"])

df2 = df[df['limit'] >= df['age']]
print df2.to_string(index=False)
```

The output is:

```
age  sex  limit
  3    1      3
  3    1      4
  3    2      3
  3    2      4
  4    1      4
  4    2      4
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic data:

```
age=[3,4,5,6]
sex=[1,2]
limit=[3,4]
```

Following code using list comprehension combines `for` and `if` to check every combination:

```
lst = [(a, s, l) 
        for a in age
        for l in limit
        if l >= a
        for s in sex]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=lst, columns=["age","sex","limit"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   age  sex  limit
0    3    1      3
1    3    1      4
2    3    2      3
3    3    2      4
4    4    1      4
5    4    2      4
```